# How to access data from vector of vector of double

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I have a variable Vertex;
How to assign data and get data from Vertex? I know one method to assign value by creating one temp variable and then Vertex.push_back(temp). Is there any directed method to assign and get data?

```
vector<vector<double>> Vertex;
vector<double> temp;
Vertex.push_back(temp); //Any other direct method?
```

Comment: try searching online for such things: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/

Comment: "Any other direct method?" How is this not direct? What are you expecting?

Comment: I don't want to use temp variable (if possible).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
vector<vector<double>> Vertex;
    for(int i=1; i<n; i++)
    {   
      Vertex.resize(i);
      Vertex[i-1].push_back(11);
    Vertex[i-1].push_back(112);
    std::cout<<Vertex[i-1][0]<<Vertex[i-1][1];
    }
```

Comment: Can someone suggest me how to change the above code if Vertex is a pointer. vector<vector<double>> *Vertex;

Answer (score 2):

Given that you have no space between `>>`, I assume using C++11 is okay? If so, you can initialiser lists, e.g.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> Vertex;
    Vertex.push_back({1.0,2.0,3.0});
    Vertex.push_back({4.5,2.5,0.5});

    std::cout << Vertex[0][1] << '\n'    // prints '2'
              << Vertex[1][2] << '\n';   // prints '0.5'
}
```

Comment: It is showing error (expected an expression).     Vertex.push_back({1.0,2.0,3.0});
Vertex.push_back({4.5,2.5,0.5});

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for `emplace_back`?

```
vector<vector<double>> Vertex;
Vertex.emplace_back();

//or

Vertex.emplace_back(100, 1.0); //Creates new vector of 100 doubles initialized with 1.0
```

Comment: I want to assign x,y,z coordinate of 5 vertexs in Vertex.

Comment: @SunilSingh `emplace_back` will forward the arguments to `value_type`'s constructor. If you know what constructor you are dealing with, you can do that.